# What this CMake Error means? My variables are set to NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to run some code from my university, but when I do "cmake .." inside "build" I get the following error:

---

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: iceutil_lib
>       linked by target "cppgui" in directory /Users/alej/Desktop/project1
>       linked by target "project1" in directory /Users/alej/Desktop/project1
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

Any of my friends are getting errors, can you help me?

Comment: I'd assume CMake fails to find [ZeroC ICE framework](https://zeroc.com/downloads/ice). Setting `Ice_HOME` CMake variable to point to directory containing the library may fix the problem.

Comment: Your answer helped me, if I set Ice_HOME cmake worked but when I typed make after that, it had problems, so I had to write another route instead, but thanks anyway!

Comment: please try `cmake -Diceutil_lib=/path/to/library ../`

Comment: I think the OP should accept an answer as solution when the solution works, just my 5 cents.

Answer (score 7):

CMake tries to find all the libraries necessary to create the library or executable you are trying to build from the code from your university.

The found paths to those libraries are stored in special variables in CMake. By default, those variables carry the value `<Library-Name>-NOTFOUND`. This `NOTFOUND` flag is what makes CMake prompt the error message.

In general there are two possible reasons, why CMake can not find the library for you:

- The library is not installed on your system
- The library is installed somewhere CMake did not search for it. In this case you can help CMake by setting the library installation path into the respective CMake variables. To do this, open the file `CMakeCache.txt` with a text editor and search for `ICEUTIL_LIB`. Replace the `blabla-NOTFOUND` value with the actual (absolute) path of the library. There might be other variables with the `ICEUTIL` prefix. One of them might be named like `ICEUTIL_HEADERS` or `ICEUTIL_INCLUDE_DIR`. Replace the value of this one with the absolute path of where the `.h` files for `ICEUTIL` are found. If the include path is not set, CMake might run fine without errors, but later you will run into compiler errors saying `include file not found`.

Comment: It seems it works. I searched for the ICEUTIL_LIB and replaced the path of the library. I didn´t found the other variables you mencioned but I guess there are not any. Thank you so much!!!!!!!